# From one component trigger scroll to top of element in another component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have this table which is part of `TableComponent`:

```
<table class="th-tracker-table th-environmental-table" #trackerTable>
```

I want to access it from `MyComponent` and scroll to top of component, when `swapProjectsGroups()` method is triggered

```
export class MyComponent {

    @ViewChild("#trackerTable") trackerTable: ElementRef;

    public swapProjectsGroups() {
        this.trackerTable.nativeElement.scrollTo(0,0); //Error: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of undefined
    }
}
```

But I get `Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of undefined`, am I missing something to initialize nativeElement?

What is the angular2 way to achieve this?

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't do it with template variable. Try to wrap your table into a component and then

```
@ViewChild(YourComponent) _yourComponent: YourComponent;
```

remember that _yourComponent is first available in ngAfterViewInit event.

Comment: it seems I needed to add nativeElement:         this.trackerTable.nativeElement.scrollTo(0,0); b
but now I get Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: this.trackerTable.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0; 
and remember about in what lifecycle event you are triggering the call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`@ViewChild("trackerTable") trackerTable: TableComponent;`